# Is the set of irrationals separable as a subspace of the real line?

Tags: general-topology

I am trying to find an example of a separable Hausdorff space which has a non-separable subspace.  This led me to ask the question in the title: is the set of irrationals, regarded as a subspace of the real line, separable or  non-separable?

A space is separable if it contains a countable dense subset.  A subset $A$ of a space $X$ is dense in $X$ if $\bar{A}=X$.

It's easy to come up with a dense set and a countable set in $\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$, since (trivially) $\overline{\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}}=\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$ in the subspace topology, and as a countable set we can take something like $\{k\pi \mid k \in \mathbb{Z}\}$.  But is there a subset that is both dense AND countable?  And of course, how do we prove the result?

Comment: For your original question, you can find a separable  space with an uncountable discrete subspace.

Comment: @azarel: But is it Hausdorff?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Sure, even Tychonoff.

Comment: @azarel: Then this is not what I had in mind. Is your space compact? :-)

Comment: @AsafKaragila No, it is not compact but I guess you could get one.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

$\Bbb R$ is second countable (i.e., has a countable base), so it’s hereditarily separable. Specifically, let $\mathscr{B}$ be the set of all open intervals with rational endpoints; $\Bbb Q$ is countable, so $\mathscr{B}$ is countable. Enumerate $\mathscr{B}=\{B_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$, and for $n\in\Bbb N$ let $x_n$ be any irrational number in $B_n$. Then $\{x_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$ is a countable dense subset of $\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q$. (Clearly the same trick works for any subset of $\Bbb R$, not just the irrationals.)

For an explicit example of such a set, let $\alpha$ be any irrational; then $\{p+\alpha:p\in\Bbb Q\}$ is a countable dense subset of $\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q$.

There are many separable Hausdorff spaces with non-separable subspaces. Two are mentioned in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/161679/12042) to an earlier question. The first is compact; the second is Tikhonov and pseudocompact. Both are therefore quite nice spaces. Both are a bit complicated, however. A simpler example is the [Sorgenfrey plane](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorgenfrey_plane) $\Bbb S$: $\Bbb Q\times\Bbb Q$ is a countable dense subset of $\Bbb S$, and $\{\langle x,-x\rangle:x\in\Bbb R\}$ is an uncountable discrete subset of $\Bbb S$ (which is obviously not separable as a subspace of $\Bbb S$).

Answer (score 10):

Every subspace of a separable metric space is separable.

For the irrationals, take the irrational algebraic numbers, those are dense in $\mathbb R$ and therefore in the irrationals too. As Jacob remarks below, if $\alpha$ is irrational, then $\{\alpha+q\mid q\in\mathbb Q\}$ is also dense.

Generally speaking, the irrationals are homeomorphic to the Baire space, the set of sequences of natural numbers, equipped with the product topology $\mathbb N^\mathbb N$.

This has a countable dense subset: eventually constant sequences.

Comment: Perhaps a simpler example of a countable dense subset of irrationals would be $\mathbb Q + \pi$.

Comment: @JacobSchlather: I have to say the first example I thought of was the algebraic numbers as well.

Comment: I was going to go with $\Bbb Q+\sqrt{2}$, personally.

Comment: Wait...*every* subspace of a separable metric space is separable? It seems like that shouldn't be true in general. (If you like, I can make that an official question for you to answer.)

Comment: @Cameron: This is true assuming countable choice. Separable metric spaces are second countable; if you take a subspace it is also second countable (relativize the base to the subspace) now choose a point from each basic open set and you have your precious separability! Without countable choice, take Cohen's first model and the D-finite subset of $\mathbb R$ as a counterexample.

Comment: Ah! Therein lies the problem: I seldom (intentionally) assume choice principles if I'm not specifically directed to do so.

Comment: @CameronBuie. To add on Asaf's comment, it's worth noting that the word 'metric space' plays a key role there. Metrizability is hereditary and so is second countability. Since in a metric space separability (also Lindelöf) is equivalent with second countability, then every subspace of a separable metric space is separable (and Lindelöf, for that matter).