# Irrationals can be separable by finding a countable dense subset.

Tags: general-topology, irrational-numbers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is the set of irrationals separable as a subspace of the real line?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/182316/is-the-set-of-irrationals-separable-as-a-subspace-of-the-real-line)

Prove the irrationals are separable directly by finding a countable dense subset.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** Algebraic numbers.

**Another hint:** Add to each rational number an irrational number.

Answer (score 3):

Take $\{q\pi  \vert q \in \mathbb Q^{\times}\}$

Comment: No real reason to exclude $q=0$, is there?

Comment: @Cameron:  If $q=0$, $q\pi = 0$ is rational.

Comment: @Jason: /facepalm/